# Default localized index.html for pelican

Tags: html, github-pages, pelican

I tried to find something that is similar to my problem, but I did not have success.

I'm using pelican to build a static **multilanguage** website and I'll use github pages to publish the content.

Being a multilanguage site (en as default) I decided to structure the output folder with separated folder for each language and use relative url to point to templates etc.. all works smoothly enough.

Just to make a first github page publish experience I used `ghp-import` and again all is working properly except for one little thing.

Also in `localhost:8000` the default homepage, all the other pages, etc have the language tag in the url, like:

localhost:8000/en/blog
localhost:8000/it/blog

the problem is that the default homepage is:

- `localhost:8000` (for localhost obviously)
- `username.github.io` (for github pages)

by landing on this page, the templates fails to load (again they are lang specific) and ever worst, all the link are broken because they do not point to any language (`localhost:8000/blog` does not exist)

What I would like to do is to make a redirection so that, when typing `username.github.io` will redirect to `username.github.io/en`

I did not find something suitable in the pelicanconf.py file..

is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SITEURL in pelicanconf to 'username.github.io/en'

That should work but the address 'username.github.io' won't work anymore.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com, please provide more details about your problem,